# SQL Server - Possible ways to find MAX and MIN in several records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm new to MSSQL and finding an elegant way to do with the followings.

I have a table called **Order** and the details are as follows.

```
orderID       orderTime                   quantity         total
***************************************************************** 
1             4/1/2013 06:00:00 AM        3                300  
2             4/1/2013 09:00:00 AM        1                100  
3             4/2/2013 07:33:00 PM        2                265  
4             4/3/2013 04:15:00 PM        1                65
*****************************************************************
```

Is it possible to give out the following output?

```
orderDate     total
*******************
4/1/2013      400   
4/3/2013      65
```

I tried to convert the orderTime into string and further group it but somehow I failed. I'm still working hard to find a way to achieve it.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - you can convert the orderTime to a date datatype and group by that. Your output seems to indicate you want a SUM rather than MIn/MAX, but you can adjust w/ the appropriate aggregation:

```
select 
  convert(date, orderTime) as 'orderDate', 
  sum(total) as 'total', 
  min(total) as 'Min', 
  max(total) as 'Max'
from Order
group by convert(date, orderTime)
order by convert(date, orderTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the orderTime to the Date data type:

```
SELECT orderDate = CONVERT(Date, orderTime)
    , total = SUM(total)
FROM dbo.Order (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY CONVERT(Date, orderTime)
ORDER BY orderDate;
```

This will return an output of:

```
orderDate     total
*******************
4/1/2013      400   
4/2/2013      265
4/3/2013      65
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data type of orderTime.  You can convert it to a date field (with no time):

```
 SELECT CAST(orderTime AS DATE), SUM(total) 
 FROM Table 
 GROUP by CAST(orderTime AS DATE);
```

--dmg